# Connection pooling in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection-pooling

Working on NodeJS backed with a MongoDB database which uses the connection pooling of MongoDB. Having a question regarding the amount of opened connections.

When we connect to mongoDB database in NodeJS with the following code:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, {  
  poolSize: 25
},function(err, db) {
    console.log('connected successfully, reuse this db object in the whole application');
    }
);
```

Was observing and testing the behaviour of the mongoDB database a bit, but had some questions regarding this.

### Question:

1. Does connection pooling automatically open and close connections in an optimal way or does the programmer need to optimize this?
2. If this can be optimized how?

Comment: Automatic, yes. Optimizing, well you sort of are the moment to set a `poolSize`. Normally there's a "default" around 5 connections which I "think" without going and looking are always maintained as a minimum. The pool only grows if concurrent requests from the event loop require a new connection, but they don't immediately close and will stay open for a while in case they are needed again. If you expect to use a lot of connections then you could "pre-heat" by sending about 20 or so parallel "trivial" requests  to the server to force the pool to grow.

Comment: The real question is, "Why do you need to know?". If there is something specific that makes you think you need a large pool of connections then you probably should explain that so you can get a definitive "yes you're right" or "no, do this instead" response to what you think you want to do. In quite a lot of scenarios though the default 5 should suffice, and if you think you need more then you really should start to question the request pattern and see if there are things you could be doing better without making as many requests. Or "as long" requests even.

Comment: If I have like 1k users who are doing ~ 5 queries a min, will I get any performance issues?

Comment: I would call that pretty small. Just stick with the default settings for that kind of load. In all honesty the bigger problems are typically with the application code itself. Questions get regularly asked here about *"awaiting my 500 promises to resolve"* from individual `.find()` requests which we can usually resolve down to *"run this **one** request instead"*. So it's those things you usually need to worry about first. Leave the "connection pool" settings for when you have significantly higher loads in the 1000's per minute range.

Answer (score 0):

*Note that I'm taking much of this from Neil's generous comments from over four years ago so that this question can be marked as answered.*

---

## Connection pool behavior

When using a connection pool, **connections are automatically established** as needed (when there's not an existing idle connection) **and released** (after a period of inactivity). You can define the scaling limits of the pool by specifying `maxPoolSize` or `minPoolSize` if desired. The default will create a connection pool with 5 connections. You can [read more about connection pools from the Mongo docs.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/connection-pool-overview/)

> If you expect to use a lot of connections then you could "pre-heat" by sending about 20 or so parallel "trivial" requests to the server to force the pool to grow.

## Optimization

You also asked about optimization. I agree with Neil, with well written queries 5,000 requests/minute should not be an issue. Should you need to tune the connection pool, you can refer to [Mongo's guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/connection-pool-performance-tuning/). **[Indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/manage-indexes/) are often more impactful to performance**, however.